# Three Table UPDATE and JOIN result in Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
UPDATE 
    CustomerShowing
SET 
    CustomerShowing.rate = 5
FROM 
    CustomerShowing
INNER JOIN 
    Showing
ON 
    CustomerShowing.showid = Showing.showid
INNER JOIN 
    Movie
ON 
    Showing.movieid = Movie.movieid
WHERE 
    Movie.name='Batman';
```

however I am receiving the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 86: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'FROM CustomerShowing  INNER JOIN Showing  ON
>   CustomerShowing.ShowingID = Showing' at line 3

How could I fix this? I am using `MySQL` version `5.5.53`.

Comment: You keep tagging SQL-Server but your error message comes from a MySQL engine. And there is no version  5.5.53 of SQL Server

Comment: You use MySQL. Trust me. And of course MySQL is installed on a server. But "SQL-Server" is a Microsoft product and something else than MySQL

Answer (score 2):

MySQL uses a different syntax than SQL-Server.

```
 UPDATE CustomerShowing
 INNER JOIN Showing ON CustomerShowing.showid = Showing.showid
 INNER JOIN Movie ON Showing.movieid = Movie.movieid
 SET CustomerShowing.rate = 5
 WHERE Movie.name='Batman';
```